# Iterate two whiles and compare items

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I want to compare that if the files that I have in a directory are the same that I have saved in the db.
Here is my code I cant see why its only iterate in the first item of the directory and not all of they:

```
$dir = opendir("galerias/programas");
    while ($elemento = readdir($dir)){
        if( $elemento != "." && $elemento != ".."){
            if( is_dir($path.$elemento) ){
                echo "<p><strong>CARPETA: ". $elemento ."</strong></p>";
            }else{
                while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tabla1)){
                    if($row['imagen'] == $elemento){
                        echo $row['imagen'];
                        echo "<br>";
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the portion of the program that creates $tabla1?

Comment: Can you post the file listing in `galerias/programas`?  Also, what query are you using to pull your records from MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner `while` loop will loop over all the results of your query only once.

If you want to iterate again over all the results of your query, your must rewind them using `mysql_data_seek($tabla1, 0);` after your inner while loop.

By the way, the old `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP, and you should consider switching to PDO or `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = opendir("galerias/programas");
    while ($elemento = readdir($dir)){
        if( $elemento != "." && $elemento != ".."){
            if( is_dir($path.$elemento) ){
                echo "<p><strong>CARPETA: ". $elemento ."</strong></p>";
            }else{
                while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tabla1)){
                    if($row['imagen'] == $elemento){
                        echo $row['imagen'];
                        echo "<br>";
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can change:

```
if( $elemento != "." && $elemento != ".."){
```

to:

```
if(!is_dir($elemento)){
```

But you would be better off just pulling a query on the DB to an array and then compare the array with in_array(). That way you can parse out your dir values and do whatever you want to with them.